# How to replace multiple occurrences in single pass?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

I have the following string:

```
abc
def
abc
xyz
pop
mmm
091
abc
```

I need to replace all occurrences of `abc` with the ones from array `["123", "456", "789"]` so the final string will look like this:

```
123
def
456
xyz
pop
mmm
091
789
```

I would like to do it without iteration, with just single expression. How can I do it?

Comment: So the nth instance of `abc` should be replaced with the nth index from the array?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without explicit iteration? (Note that it's not possible to do this without any iteration - at some point, something you do or call will be doing some iteration to solve it.)

Comment: @Matthew Watson: I like when the code is short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a "single expression version":

**edit:** Delegate instead of Lambda for 3.5

```
string[] replaces =  {"123","456","789"};
Regex regEx = new Regex("abc");
int index = 0;
string result = regEx.Replace(input, delegate(Match match) { return replaces[index++];} );
```

Test it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AhVxu7)

Comment: don't `Replace` use foreach inside? :)

Comment: @Backs It does loop internally, but as far as I know there is no way to fulfil this task without looping...

Comment: Im pretty sure op meant avoiding any loop code written by himself.
E.g. for,foreach, Linq...

Comment: @CSharpie, could you elaborate on `m => replaces[index++]` part please?

Comment: @CSharpie well, to be honest, my code has no loops to, just "functional style". so you use regex, I do not. but both solutions are wrong according to conditions.

Comment: @Pablo m => replaces[index++] is an annonymous function which is called within the replace method everytime a match is found. It returns a string which is at the given index of the array. The ++ makes sure the index is incremented for every call to this annonymous function.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Pablo That annonymous function comes as a lambdaexpression and matches the expected Delegate called MatchEvalutaor. 

You might want to look up some examples on this whole lambda thing.

Comment: It appears lambda expressions are introduced from .NET 4, whereas I am limited to 3.5 :(

Comment: Then use a delegate istead. Updated Answer + Example

Answer (score 4):

> do it without iteration, with just single expression

This example uses the static [Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses a [MatchEvaluator Delegate (System.Text.RegularExpressions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) that will replace match values from a a queue and returns a string as a result:

```
var data =
@"abc
def
abc
xyz
pop
mmm
091
abc";

var replacements = new Queue<string>(new[] {"123", "456", "789"});

string result =  Regex.Replace(data, 
                             "(abc)",   // Each match will be replaced with a new 
                              (mt) =>   // queue item; instead of a one string.
                                     { 
                                       return replacements.Dequeue();
                                     });
```

**Result**

```
123
def
456
xyz
pop
mmm
091
789
```

---

**.Net 3.5 Delegate**

> whereas I am limited to 3.5.

```
Regex.Replace(data, "(abc)",  delegate(Match match) { return replacements.Dequeue(); } )
```

Comment: @Pablo Updated for .Net 3.5.